# Implement a 3-phase commit in c#/t-sql

Tags: .net, t-sql

Simple question, probably an easy answer but google-fu seems to be weak this morning: can't find any information.

I've got a SQL Server 2008 back-end and a .net front end written in C#. I'm changing a database copy job that's administered through c# from copying one-to-one to one-to-many target databases. As part of this job I need to ensure that the data copy uses a 3-phase commit before writing. However I can find absolutely no references anywhere as to how to implement this in Microsoft technologies.

Can anyone either help here, or point me at something useful, preferably with examples?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you must have 3-phase? SQL Server comes out of the box with two-phase commits using MSDTC: [MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225991%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)